# Formation du subjonctif

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif

Quelqu'un peut-il m'expliquer comment se forme le subjonctif d'un verbe ?

Comment: Que veux-tu dire avec "je trouve qu'il est difficile de se déplacer" ?

Comment: excusez-moi, je veux dire que je vais être compliqué de continuer à étudier si je ne connaissais pas cette chose :)

Comment: Alors, je pense que tu voulais dire « Il est difficile d'avancer » ou « Il est difficile de progresser » (mieux).

Comment: Oui, peut-être ..

Comment: As (unfortunately) more and more people seem to completely avoid using any subjunctive, I would not say that it's a major issue in real life conversations.

Comment: Autre remarque: je doute que la difficulté vienne de la façon dont le subjonctif est formé, il est nettement plus difficile de l'utiliser correctement.

Comment: Maybe, but we must know it, I'd say :)

Comment: Cedric: totally false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour former le **subjonctif présent** :

- aux personnes du singulier, il faut prendre la racine donnée par la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du pluriel de l'indicatif présent et ajouter les terminaisons suivantes : *-e*, *-es*, *-e*.
- aux personnes du pluriel, on ajoute aux racines habituelles de l'indicatif les terminaisons suivantes : *-ions*, *-iez*, *-ent*.

Exemple:

> Ils **boiv**ent → que je **boiv**e, que tu **boiv**es, qu'il **boiv**e
>
> Nous **buv**ons, vous **buv**ez, ils **boiv**ent → que nous **buv**ions, que vous **buv**iez, qu'ils **boiv**ent.

Il existe neuf exceptions : *avoir*, *être*, *faire*, *pouvoir*, *savoir*, *aller*, *valoir*, *vouloir*.

L'**imparfait du subjonctif** se forme à partir de la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du singulier du passé simple et des terminaisons : *-sse*, *-sses*, *-^t* (accent circonflexe!!), *-ssions*, *-ssiez*, *-ssent*.

Le **subjonctif passé** (respectivement **plus que parfait**) se forme à partir du subjonctif présent (respectivement imparfait) de l'auxiliaire, suivi du participe passé du verbe.

Comment: Merci pour cette explication

Comment: Duh!? Je rajoute un exemple au hasard et je vois que ça marche pas… Une autre exception ?

Comment: Oui, il semble que d'autres "sortes" d'exceptions existent (voir http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/C_a_subj_formation.htm)

Comment: J'ai essayé de corriger le tir. Mais peut-être que ça ne fonctionne pas tout le temps…